# google map marker don't show

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have recently added a google map on my website . but it don't show map marker. i have used here custom color style of google map.
my site link:

> http://clavisc.com/contact/

**i have coded following bellow:**

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {  
var styles = [  
 {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 65
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 51
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 30
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 40
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "hue": "#ffff00"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -97
        }
    ]
}
];  
var options = {  
mapTypeControlOptions: {  
    mapTypeIds: ['Styled']  
},  
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.681527, 12.591067),  
    zoom: 14,  
    disableDefaultUI: true,   
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'  
};  
var div = document.getElementById('gmap');  
var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);  
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });  
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);  

};
```

Comment: There is no marker in the posted code.  Where do you expect it to be?

Comment: [Add a markers (from the documentation)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#add)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with the function call can u try this and let me know .

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){    var styles = [  
 {
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 65
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 51
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 30
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 40
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "administrative.province",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -100
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "hue": "#ffff00"
        },
        {
            "lightness": -25
        },
        {
            "saturation": -97
        }
    ]
}
];  
var options = {  
mapTypeControlOptions: {  
    mapTypeIds: ['Styled']  
},  
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.681527, 12.591067),  
    zoom: 14,  
    disableDefaultUI: true,   
    mapTypeId: 'Styled'  
};  
var div = document.getElementById('gmap');  
var map = new google.maps.Map(div, options);  
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, { name: 'Styled' });  
map.mapTypes.set('Styled', styledMapType);  
var markers=new google.maps.Marker({
                                position:new google.maps.LatLng(55.681527, 12.591067),
                                map:map,
                                title:'Clavis Capital',
                                  });

}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: where i paste this code. please give me full code with my code. i am not expert on javascript. @nitin

Comment: its working perfectly u just need to paste this script ,delete the one's which is already there

Comment: You have included map twice remove both and paste the one which i have given and it works perfect i tried it.